# How to snooze the alarm in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am developing an app which will ring alarm at a particular time. How can I snooze that alarm. If any of u have sample code  or link to that then it will be helpful.

Comment: have u implemented the snooze functionality in our app .if yes, then please help because i am also creating an alarm app with snooze functionality.Please of it is possible can u provide some sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to reschedule a new timer set to fire at the delay for your snooze functionality.

Comment: Ya i have this idea in my mind, but if their is any in built function is Objective C for the same then that will be much easier to implement. Claus, did to vote down my question?

Comment: No built-in snooze except what you code yourself, and nope it wasn't me who downvoted